# R.java does not contain new resource files in IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm using Idea 12 for Android development and I've added an extra resource file in the values folder:

```
-values
  ids.xml
  strings.xml
  intents.xml
```

intents.xml simply has some string resources.

However, when I rebuild I get a compilation error because the R object doesn't have the intents object, it's as if while rebuilding R the intents file is skipped. If I add extra resources to strings.xml those get picked up while rebuilding. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: can you post how you are referencing the strings in intents.xml in your code?

Comment: I was doing R.intents.<name> which is wrong, the correct way is R.string.<name> but I can't seem to close the question as it has a bounty :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using R wrong. I was doing

```
R.intents.<name>
```

instead of

```
R.string.<name>
```

Answer (score 1):

-Make sure that your are not importing Android.R .. if so, remove this import.

-Make sure that your R.java class is exist into the "gen" folder to be able to use them.

-Make sure all your XML files are saved to the final edit, sometimes eclipse does not save the new modification. If so, restart your eclipse.

-Check All your XML headers to be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and any Double declairation of the android::xtools

I hope this helps

Comment: - I don't have any android.R references
- the R.java file in the gen folder is empty, that's a feature in IntelliJ, the proper R is handled internally.
- All my XML files are saved, I'm using IntelliJ
- My headers are like that